# Adding Headers to a List

Tags: android, list, header, xamarin, listadapter

In Xamarin, I have coded a List as follows:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    items = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    //Header displaying Locations
    items.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Fiji", "A nice beach"));
    items.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Beijing", "AKA Shanghai"));
    //Header displaying plants
    items.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Seedlings", "Tiny plants"));
    items.Add(new Tuple<string,string>("Plants", "Green plants"));

    ListAdapter = new List_Adapter(this, items);
}
```

This List is displaying correctly.

My question is this: How can I add Headers to this List?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<listView>.addHeaderView(View);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
listView.addHeaderView(...);
```

on your listview instance.

EDIT:

You should call the *listView.addHeaderView(...)* _BEFORE_ you set the adapter to the listview.
For example:

```
View v = // inflate here the header view
listView.addHeaderView(v);
listView.setAdapter(/* you adapter instance */);
```

Comment: Can you please explain where to write this in the above code?

Comment: I am not sure how to inflate the header view. Can you write some quick code that will work with my code in the OP?

Comment: Also, I am not using a listView object, I am using a List<Tuple<string, string>>();

Comment: Then where you use the listAdapter? Do not you need to connect it with a listview?